# Merge two Maven projects ?

Tags: eclipse, maven, merge, project

I have two Maven projects that I would like to merge in Eclipse. I have imported them via the Eclipse Plugin m2e and now I would like them to be one project as opposed to two separate ones. Is that possible ?

Comment: What are you really trying to achieve? What's wrong with having two projects open in Eclipse? Are you really thinking of merging them for good, or just looking at them in Eclipse as if they were a single project?

Comment: @SanderVerhagen I am trying to create a server side java project and I have two libraries that have to play together...

Comment: Sure, modularization, you'd want to have some shared stuff in one project, some more stuff in another project, then tie it all together in... say... a WAR project. You would develop these as separate projects, and open these alongside each other in Eclipse. Then, m2e will take care of "workspace resolution", so that when you change some code, the dependent projects will immediately "see" the changes. Does that makes sense?

Comment: Kind of ... I have started to work with Maven just today, so this is a little overwhelming at the moment...

Comment: Make some modules that makes sense, make your WAR project dependent on them. Have the different projects open separately in Eclipse. Then perhaps formulate a new question for what you're really stuck with.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem with a big project which had lot of modules. I wanted modules to be in a single project rather than each module as a new project.

While importing in eclipse, uncheck option **'search for nested project'**

[Reference](http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/Import-multi-module-Maven-project-as-one-Eclipse-project-td140015.html)